# build file browser in node, Jade and express

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

I had this Idea that I can use Jade to replace the `<input type="file">` and I managed to build the read dir bit but now I need help getting a function call from the Jade document to the file hosting the Jade variables, doc tree:
'/'
    'routes'
        'index.js'
    'views'
        'layout.jade'
        'index.jade'
    'public'
        'index.html'
        'src'
             'main.js'

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');

var dir = fs.readdirSync("/", 'utf8');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Klaudd Manager', dir: dir });
});
module.exports = router;
```

and the jade file:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        h2= title
        ul
            for item in dir
                li= item
```

so I was wondering how I would be able to send a function call to that index.js file from within the Jade file, How do I do it?

ps. I have search google for at least half an hour for this.

I thank you sincerely for any advice and / or help...
 - Jacob

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  You can embed Javascript in the jade file in `<script>` tags and it will then be client-side Javascript in the browser when the page is rendered and loaded by the browser.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, I'm not the best at explaining myself... i'm sorry

Comment: FYI, `<input type="file">` is a client-side file picker.  You can't emulate that in either client-side Javascript or in server-side Javascript because neither can access the client-side file system.

Comment: I managed to list files with the node module FS. I just need a way to tell node to list the files in a different DIR

Comment: `fs.readdir()` or `fs.readdirSync()` take a path to the directory you want to list the files in.  That's described in [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback).

Comment: I know that. I have used it to read the contents of my home dir, on the client side

Comment: Then, what's the question?

Comment: I need to tell the index.js file that instead of loading the '/' dir, it should load the '/home' dir when the user selects the home dir in the ul

Comment: Since that's a client-side action (selecting the home directory in the page), it sounds like you need to write client-side Javascript to make an Ajax call to your server, implement a route on the server for that ajax call that fetches the desired files, return the file list as the response to the ajax call, then write client-side Javascript to process the response and modify the current page to show the new list of files.

Comment: I thought ajax was PHP based. but ok

Comment: Ajax just makes http requests to a server.  You can have any type of server listening for that request.  You can define a route in your node.js server for any number of ajax requests, just like you would for browser pages except that Ajax requests can return data that isn't HTML such as JSON.

Comment: I mean clearly, I have a lot to learn, don't I?